# Prevent XmlDocument from interpreting HTML Code

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I built a proxy to modify XML-Formatted data on the fly.

The problem is that some XML documents contain *HTML Decimal Code* within attributes and gets interpreted by XmlDocument.LoadXml method.

**Example of an input document:**

```
<config>
   <var name="CultureCode" value="fr-FR" />
   <var name="CurrencyFormatting">
      <var name="Symbol"               value="&#8364;" />
      <var name="Code"                 value="EUR"/>
      <var name="ThousandSeparator"    value=" " />
      <var name="DecimalSeparator"    value="," />
   </var>  
</config>
```

I use the following method to modify this piece of XML :

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString); //Decodes HTML Decimal Code
            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//var[@name='DecimalSeparator']");
            node.Attributes["value"].Value = ".";
            string modified = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

But, the problem is that the resulting XML contains no more `&#8364;` but the `€` sign, which is misinterpreted by the process downstream.

```
<config>
   <var name="CultureCode" value="fr-FR" />
   <var name="CurrencyFormatting">
      <var name="Symbol"               value="€" /> <!-- Value has changed -->
      <var name="Code"                 value="EUR"/>
      <var name="ThousandSeparator"    value=" " />
      <var name="DecimalSeparator"    value="." />
   </var>  
</config>
```

How can I prevent this behavior? Is there any other package that would not interpret by default HTML Code?

I could replace '€' from the resulting string but I will never be sure that another piece of HTML Decimal Code has been interpreted, which is not ideal.

Comment: The problem is that what is doing `XmlDocument` is legit and necessary: there are many characters that are illegal inside an attribute and so they must be escaped, so it is quite normal to have escape characters inside an attribute, and it is quite normal for `XmlDocument` to unescape them.

Comment: Did you try changing `&#8364;` to `&amp;#8364;`? at your input XML?

Comment: @xanatos understood. So, as a workaround, how can I reverse this process and escape back all attributes?

Comment: Now... I've done some research and I'm 75% sure that `XmlReader` and `XmlTextReader` (the readers used by nearly all the .NET classes) unescape xml entities. You can't control it. You could work on the `XmlWriter` side, but it remains a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said, it is a pain. `XmlReader` and `XmlTextReader` (that are the readers used by `XmlDocument` and nearly all the other "advanced" xml classes of .NET) automatically unescape all the xml char entities they encounter, and there is no way to disable this. So unless one rewrites big chunks of `XmlReader` it is impossible to preserve the original xml char entities. What one can do is work on the `XmlWriter` side. It is still a pain.

```
public class EscapedXmlWriter : XmlWriter
{
    // Note that normally XmlWriter uses hex escapes
    public bool UseHexCharEntities { get; set; } = false;

    protected XmlWriter Writer;

    public EscapedXmlWriter(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Writer = writer;
    }

    public override System.Xml.WriteState WriteState => Writer.WriteState;

    public override void Flush() => Writer.Flush();

    public override string LookupPrefix(string ns) => Writer.LookupPrefix(ns);

    public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count) => Writer.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);

    public override void WriteCData(string text) => Writer.WriteCData(text);

    public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch) => Writer.WriteCharEntity(ch);

    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count) => Writer.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);

    // We could give to comments the same treatment of attributes and content 
    public override void WriteComment(string text) => Writer.WriteComment(text);

    public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset) => Writer.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);

    public override void WriteEndAttribute() => Writer.WriteEndAttribute();

    public override void WriteEndDocument() => Writer.WriteEndDocument();

    public override void WriteEndElement() => Writer.WriteEndElement();

    public override void WriteEntityRef(string name) => Writer.WriteEntityRef(name);

    public override void WriteFullEndElement() => Writer.WriteFullEndElement();

    public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text) => Writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);

    public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count) => Writer.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);

    public override void WriteRaw(string data) => Writer.WriteRaw(data);

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns) => Writer.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);

    public override void WriteStartDocument() => Writer.WriteStartDocument();

    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone) => Writer.WriteStartDocument(standalone);

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns) => Writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{Writer.WriteState}: {text}");

        var isAttribute = Writer.WriteState == System.Xml.WriteState.Attribute;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            char ch = text[i];
            char low;

            if (ch == '"' && isAttribute)
            {
                sb.Append("&quot;");
            }
            if (ch == '\'' && isAttribute)
            {
                // XmlWriter doesn't escape ' in attributes because it always uses the form "xyz" instead of the form 'xyz'
                sb.Append("&apos;");
            }
            else if (ch == '&')
            {
                sb.Append("&amp;");
            }
            else if (ch == '<')
            {
                sb.Append("&lt;");
            }
            else if (ch == '>')
            {
                sb.Append("&gt;");
            }
            else if (i + 1 < text.Length && char.IsHighSurrogate(ch) && char.IsLowSurrogate(low = text[i + 1]))
            {
                int utf32 = char.ConvertToUtf32(ch, low);

                if (UseHexCharEntities)
                {
                    sb.Append("&#x");
                    sb.Append(utf32.ToString("X"));
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append("&#");
                    sb.Append(utf32);
                }

                sb.Append(';');

                i++;
            }
            else if (ch < 0x20 || ch > 0x7f)
            {
                if ((ch == '\r' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t') && !isAttribute)
                {
                    sb.Append(ch);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (UseHexCharEntities)
                    {
                        sb.Append("&#x");
                        sb.Append(((int)ch).ToString("X"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("&#");
                        sb.Append((int)ch);
                    }

                    sb.Append(';');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(ch);
            }
        }

        string text2 = sb.ToString();
        Writer.WriteRaw(text2);
    }

    public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar) => Writer.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);

    public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws) => Writer.WriteWhitespace(ws);

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Writer.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

This is an `EscapedXmlWriter` that will escape all the characters `< 0x20` or `> 0x7f` (so it will escape anything that is a control character or a non-ascii character). It will preserve new lines/line feeds/tabs in the content, because otherwise the content would become illegible. There is even special handling for non-BMP characters ( for example). And there is an option `UseHexCharEntities` to control if it should use hex or decimal escaping.

Use it like:

```
using (var writer = new EscapedXmlWriter(XmlWriter.Create("out.xml", new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
})))
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

    // THIS!
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

The `XmlWriter.Create()` is quite flexible. You can "connect" it to a `StringBuilder` or a `Stream` or a `StringWriter`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings { ... })
```